# Upgrading Rails Dev Unit from Snow Leopard to Lion

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Should I take any considerations for my Rails 3.0/3.1, Ruby 1.9.2 development machine running OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard before upgrading to OS X 10.7 Lion?

Will there be anything that I need to reinstall? Finally should I backup my gem sets somehow?

Comment: Check the [App Compatibility Table](http://roaringapps.com/apps:table). You might also want to consult the StackOverflow community.

Comment: No definite answer, but generally it *shouldn't* be a problem. If you want to make sure, you can always reinstall (recompile) Ruby. Backing up everything is something you should do anyway :P

Comment: Sounds good guys, thanks. I run time machine hourly so I couldn't imagine there being any un-restorable changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X (including Lion) comes bundled with it's own version of ruby, which will probably overwrite your current version.  (I'm not sure if Lion is using 1.8.7 or 1.9*)  But the worst that could happen is you'll have to upgrade to 1.9.2 after upgrading to Lion.

This shouldn't be difficult, but you may also have to reinstall all your custom gems, etc. I would suggest using [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) to manage Ruby independent of the local version on your machine.  It painlessly allows you to keep track of any version of ruby you want per application so you don't have to fool around with your machine's version and other applications that may depend on it.

IE You could have one application using 1.8.7 and another using 1.9.2 each with their own set of gems and no conflict between them or your machine which may have it's own version as well.

There's a screencast demonstrating RVM on [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/200-rails-3-beta-and-rvm).

Comment: Thanks lewombie! I'm using RVM right now so I imagine the re-install would be painless.

Comment: No problem, you can also create a .rvmrc file that goes in the root directory which instructs RVM exactly which version of Ruby is needed, so you don't have to manually remember to switch and it makes it easy to share the code with others.

Comment: I've been doing that in my projects to automatically change gemsets but I never realized that I can do it my root directory! Thanks again!